# Call stored procedure with custom type parameter from c#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, orm

I have a procedure with a custom type as follow:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
    @Arg1 CustomArgType readonly
AS
BEGIN
.
.
.
END
```

And where the custom type is:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.CustomArgType as TABLE
(
    SomeInt int not null
)
```

How can I call the above stored procedure in c#?

What kind of adapter can be used? Can an ORM like EF work with such a stored procedure?

Comment: "Table valued parameters" - raw ado.net certainly can (although how well it works depends on the scenario)

Answer (score 0):

To test that, I extended your stored proc to make it return the first row of the parameter table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
    @Arg1 CustomArgType readonly
AS
BEGIN
    select top 1 SomeInt from @Arg1
END
```

Now I can use the following code in C# to execute the stored procedure:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=temp;User ID=sa"))
{
    conn.Open();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("SomeInt", typeof(Int32));

    dt.Rows.Add(new Object[] { 3 });

    var command = conn.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "MyProc";
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Arg1", dt));
    object returnValue = command.ExecuteScalar();

}
```

`returnValue` is 3 which I expected (I inserted into the 1st row in the parameter table).

Unfortunately I don't know much about EF so I can't say if you can do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your table parameter as "Structured", and set its value to your list/table variable in C#. Example code below:

```
try
{
     using (var conn = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
     using (var command = new SqlCommand("MyProc", conn)
     {
           CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
     })
     {
          command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Arg1", SqlDbType.Structured));
          command.Parameters["@Arg1"].Value = myArgVariable;
          command.Parameters["@Arg1"].TypeName = "dbo.CustomArgType"; 
          conn.Open();
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     throw;
}
```

Reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/felixmar/2010/10/27/how-to-create-and-execute-a-stored-procedure-using-a-table-as-a-parameter/